# How to get round 'The wait operation timed out'

Tags: c#, database, linq, bulkinsert, connection-timeout

I'm in the middle of building an ecommerce system with c. 10000 products, each with 15 varieties, each with a unique price to match, so c. 150,000 product prices. Prices vary every day, and these are sent to us in a CSV and we automate an import to re-write the entire database table of new prices, as over 95% of prices will change every day. Because of the number, we have a flag against each price indicating whether that price is the one visible on the website.

After we import, the prices that were on the site yesterday (and hence marked as visible), and the prices that are new and not on the site yet have their flags switched in the C# console line program, with this LINQ command:-

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[ProductVariationPrice] SET IsVisible = IsVisible ^ 1");
```

so everything that was marked as IsVisible is now not visible and vice versa. This takes less than a second even for 300,000 rows, and then we delete the range of rows that are set to IsVisible = 1.

Before this we use BulkInsert to insert the rows quickly, and LINQ's `RemoveRange` to remove the invisible items to be deleted.

Initially this was fine, but I'm now getting users who are on the ecommerce site, get 'The wait operation timed out' error at the exact period that the data flags are switching over and the old data is being removed.

How can I stop this wait operation timing out during this period? Things I've been told we cannot do:-

- Update each record instead of re-writing the entire table (takes far too long)
- Lock everyone out of the system for a period while the new prices come in.

Could anyone advise? Is it a case of keeping the database connection open for longer?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Here is the full code around the bottleneck:-

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[ProductVariationPrice] SET IsVisible = IsVisible ^ 1");
    transaction.Complete();
}

List<ProductVariationPrice> oldProductPrices = db.ProductVariationPrices.Where(x => !x.IsVisible).ToList();
db.ProductVariationPrices.RemoveRange(oldProductPrices);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: how long does the delete take? is it in a transaction? if so, what else is in the transaction? what are the things that are timing out? presumably this is talking to the similar data - what is the isolation level of the read queries? and what is the isolation level of the write queries? and the isolation level of the transaction(s)?

Comment: Hi, unsure on what isolation levels are (let me google). The SQL switch you see above is inside a transaction. The delete is not. Could that be the issue? The pages that are failing, is the order basket page, presumably because it is pulling back those same prices... ? Delete takes a minute or two at most.

Comment: if you're using LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework (you mention LINQ, but that is ambiguous), then it will use a transaction automatically when you call `SubmitChanges()` (or whatever it is) - so yes, that would absolutely be a problem. Any reason you can't just use a single `DELETE ... WHERE ...`  here?

Comment: I've just added the full code around the bottleneck for you. Can you suggest what is the bottleneck here?

Comment: 1. If your table `ProductVariationPrice` has many (millions or more) records any update could take a while. 2. Also if there are many records and also index(es) on column `IsVisible` the update could take a while as the indexes all have to be updated too. 3. The delete from the Linq statement will always execute a delete statement per record so this is an inefficient way to execute a delete if the delete resulted in a lot of deletes (100,000 deletes would be 100,000 delete statements which are executed one at a time), use a sql statement instead like you do with the update.

Comment: (*continuation*). Use the same practice as earlier and wrap this in a transaction. `lwc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[ProductVariationPrice] WHERE IsVisible = 0");`

Comment: Thank you. Doing this now and will get back to you. Noticing the same thing for another table where we do the same, with 200,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Change your approach. You don't need to delete the records and then insert them again. The insert operation is not less costly than an update (actually it depends on multiple factors). And the already forbidden idea of updating the records from C# code is terrible. Instead, do it like this:

`Import the CSV file to additional, working table in the database.`

Don't forget to add the primary key. If you don't need transaction log over the updates use TRUNCATE, or just DROP and recreate the working table. That will be a lot faster than DELETE rows from it. Also consider using TEMPORARY table.

`Write a query to update the records in the original table by joining the records in the working/TEMPORARY table you just imported.`

That would be it.

Of course, you can make use of your `IsVisible` flag, depending on your situation, but I think it won't be needed any more.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I wondered about temporary tables and `TRUNCATE` too. But if I truncated, wouldn't I have a period where there are no prices at all?

Comment: I meant to `TRUNCATE` the temporary table before each import; not the original one. See... perform all the dirty operations on aside table. Once you have current price next to a PK in the temporary table, issue the `UPDATE` statement against the main table with `INNER JOIN` to the temporary table on the PK.